# Where did Octan come from? Why was it chosen?

Tags: lego-group, city

I have many sets that include the Octan logo:
[image: Octan Logo]

Over time Octan has been the name of LEGO Cities, Oil Companies, and Big Businesses. It was chosen as a successor to Esso and Shell. It became big during the LEGO Movie too.

Why was the name Octan chosen, and what does it mean or refer to?

Comment: http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/2488/lego-and-fuel-company-commercial-relationship/2630#2630 already discussed this actually

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Octan, is simply Octane in Danish, which is a chemical in and associated with gasoline making it a sensible name for a fictional petroleum/energy company.

The LEGO Group (under pressure by a Greenpeace campaign) stopped the previous corporate partnerships, which had featured real world oil companies logos in LEGO sets, to distance themselves from the environmental protests associated with those companies.

All this can be found here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octan